# How to add fading animation?

Tags: html, css

I just finished creating some moving boxes. For instance, when a user open the page, the boxes will fade in and move.

I have searched for some tutorial on fading animation but I don't know how to add them into my code. I am stuck on how to make them fade while moving.

Below is my code:

```css
.left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: right;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.line {
  border-left: 3px solid green;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 370px;
}

.point {
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes left {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  from {
    right: -480px;
  }
  to {
    right: -380px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center">Our Milestone</p>
<div class="line"></div>
<span class="point" style="left:364px; top:85px"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span>
<span class="point" style="left:364px; top:240px"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span>
<span class="point" style="left:364px; top:380px"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span>
<span class="point" style="left:364px; top:520px"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span>

<div class="left" style="top:0px">1st</div><br><br>
<div class="right" style="top:14px">2nd</div><br><br>
<div class="left" style="top:25px">3rd</div><br><br>
<div class="right" style="top:19px">4th</div><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add opacity to the keyframes,

```
@keyframes left {
from {left: 0px;opacity:1;}
to {left: 100px;opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes right {
from {right: -480px;opacity:1;}
to {right: -380px;opacity:0;}
}
```